# Get number of physical processors inside virtual machine

Tags: c++, assembly, virtual-machine, cpu

I'd like to know if there's a way to learn the number of physical CPU-s of a host computer when my code is running inside a VM.

I'm looking for C++/assembly solutions that run in Windows and under VmWare (workstation/esxi) and HyperV. Sorry for the very vague question but after several searches, I'm not sure if this is possible to do *inside* the virtual machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very concept of VM is that your code (even your OS) do not know that they are sharing resources.

So in first intance, no. The only possible workaround would be if the VM provided it explicity (I am thinking of VMWare Tools, yet I do not know if they offer an API for you).

Comment: there's definietely a way to get this information using VM API-s. The guest OS has a way to identify that it's a VM but I'm not sure if it's possible to get more detailed hardware information through the same channels. (For VmWare, a bit of assembly code tells that it's VmWare. For HyperV, it's a WMI query.) The VM API-s usually involve opening a port to the host to get more information - I'm hoping for something that gets the job done within the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I suspected that it may be impossible to get this level of detail. I was still hoping for way to do this.